# storage variables available on each tab or window while browser is on

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

localStorage is domain specific and stays forever, until deleted.

sessionStorage - stays for a browser session - and it is page specific

Is there a session storage - domain specific?

I need some storage variables to be available on each opened tab/window while a browser is running and deleted when browser is turned off.

In short - simmilar to php variables.

As I can see - developers didn't create such an option (sub-question: why?) but maybe some workaround exists.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, so create a session variable and try to access them in another page of the sam domain - it's not possible by me.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, no, definition of a session is - a browser session - and not - a page session

Comment: Here is what the docs say: **Each top-level browsing context has a unique set of session storage areas, one for each origin.** - here is the definition of a top-level browsing context: **https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context** - works as designed.

Comment: In other words, no, you cannot gain access to one "session's" storage from a different "session"

Comment: @RandyCasburn, I see the definition of a session differs by php and js. But definitions are not my question. Pls, read my post again.

Comment: This: _Is there a session storage - domain specific?_ answer is Yes. You'll need to use `localStorage` to have access _on each opened tab/window while a browser is running_ and manually manage the data being _deleted when browser is turned off._

Comment: @RandyCasburn - and that's what I mean - `developers didn't create such an option`. Thanks.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - `session storage which I need to delete manually` - that's ridiculous.

Comment: Like you said, "session differs by php and js" - no matter how much you want to use PHP definitions in the browser it will be difficult for you if you continue to do that. Sorry about that.

Comment: there must be a reason why browsers adopted such a stupid concept.